# Breeze OData: Get single entry with GetEntityByKey (EntitySetController)

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, odata, breeze

Reading the [documentation in Breeze website](http://www.breezejs.com/documentation/query-examples#queryByKey), to retrieve a single entity have to use the `fetchEntityByKey`.

```
manager.fetchEntityByKey(typeName, id, true)
    .then(successFn)
    .fail(failFn)
```

### Problem 1: Metadata

When trying to use this method, an error is displayed because the metadata has not yet been loaded. More details [about the error here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14803621/breezejs-entitymanager-metadatastore-and-fetchentitybykey).

The result is that whenever I need to retrieve a single entity, have to check if the metadata is loaded.

```
manager = new breeze.EntityManager(serviceName);
successFn = function(xhr) {}
failFn = function(xhr) {};
executeQueryFn = function() {
  return manager.fetchEntityByKey(typeName, id, true).then(successFn).fail(failFn);
};
if (manager.metadataStore.isEmpty()) {
  return manager.fetchMetadata().then(executeQueryFn).fail(failFn);
} else {
  return executeQueryFn();
}
```

#### Question

How can I extend the breeze, creating a `Get` method to check if metadata is loaded, and if not, load it?

### Problem 2: OData and EntitySetController

I would use the OData standard (with `EntitySetController`) in my APIs.
[This page in Breeze documentation](http://www.breezejs.com/documentation/odata) shows how, then follow [this tutorial](http://briannoyes.net/CommentView,guid,c66c5a98-384c-4abf-b11d-2b1993b041cf.aspx#commentstart) to deploy my app with OData.

The problem as you can see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17037026/breeze-odata-getentitybykey-entitysetcontroller) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16240063/retrieving-entries-by-key-without-using-filter-in-breezejs), is that the `EntitySetController` follows the odata pattern, to retrieve an entity must use `odata/entity(id)`, or to retrieve all entities you can use  `odata/entity'.

**Example**

In controller:

```
[BreezeController]
public class passosController : EntitySetController<Passo>
{
    [HttpGet]
    public string Metadata()
    {
        return ContextProvider.Metadata();
    }

    [HttpGet, Queryable(AllowedQueryOptions = AllowedQueryOptions.All, PageSize = 20)]
    public override IQueryable<T> Get()
    {
        return Repositorio.All();
    }   

    [HttpGet]
    protected override T GetEntityByKey(int key)
    {
        return Repositorio.Get(key);
    }    
}
```

When I use:

```
manager = new breeze.EntityManager("/odata/passos");
manager.fetchEntityByKey("Passo", 1, true)
    .then(successFn)
    .fail(failFn)
```

The url generated is: `/odata/passos/Passos?$filter=Id eq 1`
The correct should be: `/odata/passos(2)`

#### Question

How can I modify Breeze for when use `fetchEntityByKey` to retrieve entity use `odata/entity(id)`?